# Finding the Average Value of a function on an Interval

Tags: calculus

How would I find the average value of $f(x)=x\sin{(x^2)}$ on the interval $[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},\sqrt{\pi}]$?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Average_of_a_function

Answer (score 2):

For any function $f$,
the average value of $f$
on $[a, b]$
is
$\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Hint on $\int x \sin(x^2)dx$:
$(x^2)' = 2x$.